# In C++20, is a macro considered "active" if it's #undef'd, then #define'd again?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider

```
#define VER 1
#undef VER
#define VER 2

#if defined(VER) // #1
#error VER is defined 
#endif
```

[[cpp.import]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp.import#6):

> A macro directive is *active* at a source location if it has a point of definition in that translation unit preceding the location, and does not have a point of undefinition in that translation unit preceding the location.

My understanding is that `VER` has a *point of undefinition* preceding `#1` (the `#undef VER`), and thus it is not considered *active*. That is, `defined(VER)` should expand to `0`, and the `#error` directive should not be in effect.

But in practice, all compilers produce an error saying `VER is defined` (which agrees with my intuition, but not with my understanding of the standard).

Is my understanding incorrect? What did I miss?

Comment: not a language lawyer, but I think you need to take into account 5: "Each #define directive encountered when preprocessing each translation unit in a program results in a distinct macro definition." I understand this as `#define VER 1` and `#define VER 2` being distinct macro definitions, just by chance they share the same name

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Nice. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I am not yet quite convinced myself. Maybe I will add it as answer after some more reading

Comment: @DmitrySazonov we know how it "works". The question is about the wording in the standard which is slightly confusing and a wiki article cannot help with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see if I can lawyer that.

The paragraphs above where the link points say:

> 5. Each #define directive encountered when preprocessing each translation unit in a program results in a distinct macro definition.

So, `#define VER 1` is a definition, and `#define VER 2` is a distinct one.

> 5.1 The point of definition of a macro definition within a translation unit is the point at which its #define directive occurs

Both have a point of definition, obviously.

> 5.2 The point of undefinition of a macro definition within a translation unit is the first point at which a #undef directive naming the macro occurs after its point of definition, [...]

And `#define VER 1` has a point of undefinition, while `#define VER 2` doesn't.

Therefore, the macro definition of `#define VER 2` is active at the location of the test. At some earlier points, `#define VER 1` would be active instead.

---

Then again, if you were to do this:

```
#define X 1
#define X 2
#undef X

/* is X active now ??? */
```

There wouldn't seem to be a "point of undefinition" for the first `#define`, but I think you'd run afoul of

> 7 If a macro would be replaced or redefined, and multiple macro definitions are active for that macro name, the active macro definitions shall all be valid redefinitions of the same macro

because they're not the same macro. (There's examples in the [cpp.replace](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp.replace) page.) Though GCC and Clang accept that with a warning, with the obvious semantics of redefining it with the new value (and not e.g. stacking the definitions so that `#undef` would only remove one -- that way lies madness.)

Comment: Both definitions of `X` get a point of undefinition from the one `#undef`—it does name their macro—but they violate [cpp.replace.general]/2.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, one has to realize that according to [*macro difinition* from standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp.import#5) the two `define`s in your code result in **two distinct macro definitions**. Which means they can be considered logically different entities. From standard:

> Each #define directive encountered when preprocessing each translation unit in a program results in a distinct macro definition.

And so, since the first `VER` is different macro definition than the second `VER`, the expression `defined(VER)` is true in agreement with the standard. The only thing these macros have in common is their name but it does not exhaustively define them.